# Typing on Ipad and Ipad app.

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes I have to use a Ipad to answer some question and it is really a battle. Maybe it is just some need of practice, but if I would, for example, take five minutes to answer a question with a keyboard, with the Ipad I take ten or more.

I am asking this question to know if there is some way to avoid this problem? (Yes, I know that I can use a keyboard, but in some places it is really hard to use a keyboard)

The problem is that each symbol is in a different tab and hence, we have to keep changing tabs.

I would like to ask another question, which is somehow related: does anyone thinked about the idea of have a Ipad "app" for mathstack? I dont know, maybe something where we can at least read and make some comments.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the issue seems to just be the on-screen keyboard; I use a bluetooth keyboard with my iPad and answering questions is no harder than on a laptop.  What do you mean by "have to use" - no one is required to be on SE at a certain time, right, so can you just opt to not be available at those times?

Comment: @half-integerfan, yes you are right, I am not obliged to do anything here, however, I don't know if you will understand it, but there is sometimes when the discussion about some question/answer is so exciting, that I want to participate on it, or maybe there is some interesting question that I want to answer, so I use the mean that I have in the present time, which sometimes is an Ipad. In the end, it is not usual for me to use a Ipad to answer something here, but when I do, is like a said, a battle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SE is developing  both Android and iOS apps. They began with the Android version which is [available for testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200); iOS app will come later.

**Update**: forget   the SE app: it will not render TeX, let alone optimizing keyboard for it. Source: [Please add TeX rendering on the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213825)

The best solution I know is to acquire an app that adds the relevant TeX symbols to the keyboard, and type your post in that application.   [TeX Equation](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tex-equation/id390366359?mt=8) looks good to me, with the current price  of \$0.99. From a [review](http://www.futurebird.com/2011/using-latex-on-the-ipad-a-review-of-the-best-and-worst-apps-for-writing-mathematics/):

> includes customizable macros that allow you to speed up your coding by simplifying repetitive character strings. [...] The keyboard is well thought out, including letters, common latex characters and numbers on the same screen so most equations are easy to type without switching.

There is a also  free app [MathBot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id386825681?mt=8), which, being free, appears to be not as carefully designed.

Comment: When is the planned release date for i-products?